# Custom assign operator for Python class

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

I want to write a Python class that behaves/looks similar to win32com Excel cell assignment (need to wrap it). I want to have a comparable behaviour, i.e.

```
ws.Cells(r,c).Value = x   # win32com

myws.setCell(r,c,v)       # "classical" object method in Python

myws(r,c).Value = x       # what I want / need with my own class

myws.Cells(r,c).Value = x # what I want / need with my own class
```

I found, that it is possible to use the `__setattr__` method, but this is not the same, since I want to mix both styles `myws.x[r][c] = v` and `myws.setCell(r,c,v)`.

I even don't know how to realize `myws.x[r][c] = v` by `__setattr__`.

Is this possible?

EDIT:
I don't want to copy win32com, but I want to build a wrapper for value assignment that looks similar (not identical) to win32com, since I build up my Excel content dynamically and write to Excel with one call at the end, when I know all the cells.

EDIT2:
This doesn't work:

```
class Cells():

    def __init__(self):
        self.Value = 0

        
class Worksheet(object):

    def __init__(self):        
        self.cells = []
        
    def Cells(self,r,c):
        cell = Cells()
        self.cells.append(cell)
        return cell

ws = Worksheet()

ws.Cells(1,1).Value = 42
print(ws.Cells(1,1).Value)
print(ws.cells)
```

Comment: You will also need `__setitem__` (and the respective `__get...__` methods and maybe `__call__`) for this. You should first play around with the methods to see how they work.

Comment: `__setattr__` is not useful here if I understand the problem description. You want `__setitem__` for square-bracket syntax, and `__call__` for parenthesis syntax (I strongly recommend against this). To make the `__call__` approach work, you will need a proxy to represent a cell. To make `myws[r][c]` work, you will need to use `__getitem__` to receive `r` and return a proxy for a row, then have the proxy's `__setitem__` accept `c` and set the cell value.

Comment: In Excel object model there are 2 object types (classes) : the 'workbook' and the 'cell'. so you  may need to have two classes in Python: Workbook, Cell

Comment: I could show an example; but since you are asking about a general *technique*, it would be better to have a simple, complete, [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question. It doesn't need to interface with a spreadsheet or anything, but it should model a 2-dimensional storage of data in some way (perhaps with nested lists).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, discussion with  a colleague lead to following solution:

```
class myCell():

    def __init__(self):
        self.Value = 0

class myWorksheet(object):
    """
    wrapper for very fast writing of values to Excel via win32com
    """

    def __init__(self):        
        self.cells = defaultdict(myCell)
        self.minr = float('inf')
        self.maxr = 0
        self.minc = float('inf')
        self.maxc = 0
                
    def Cells(self,r,c):
        self.minr = min(self.minr,r)        
        self.maxr = max(self.maxr,r)    
        self.minc = min(self.minc,c)
        self.maxc = max(self.maxc,c)
        
        return self.cells[(r,c)]
        
    def toArray(self):
        a = [[None]*(self.maxc-self.minc+1) for row in range(self.minr,self.maxr+1)]

        for idx in self.cells.keys():
            r = idx[0]-self.minr
            c = idx[1]-self.minc

            a[r][c] = self.cells[idx].Value

        return a
        
    def __str__(self):
    
        a = self.toArray()
        s = []
        for row in a:
            s.append("["+",".join(["%10s" % c for c in row])+"]")
                
        return "\n".join(s)

    def writeCells(self,ws):
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(self.minr,self.minc),ws.Cells(self.maxr,self.maxc)).Value = self.toArray()
        
ws = Worksheet()

ws.Cells(1,1).Value = 42
ws.Cells(1,2).Value = 43
ws.Cells(1,1).Value = 24
ws.Cells(3,3).Value = "maxCell"
print(ws.Cells(1,1).Value)
print(ws.Cells(1,2).Value)

print(ws)

# if win32com is used, the real worksheet ws can be handed over 
# fws.writeCells(ws)
```

This results in following output:

```
24
43
[        24,        43,      None]
[      None,      None,      None]
[      None,      None,   maxCell]
```

The final array I can hand over to the win32com Range function and set all data at once in Excel wich is much faster than setting each cell one after the other but looks and feels like the orginal win32com call.